# Writing /public directory in PlayFramework after deployment to production

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

In PlayFramework 2.2.x after using `play dist` I am having issues reading and writing to `/public` directory. Is that a known problem? Is the only solution to read/write to another directory with a global path?

This is my sample code:

```
    val imageDirectory = "images/twitpics/"
    val localPrefix = "/public/"
    val publicPrefix = "/assets/"

    val files = Play.getFile(localPrefix + imageDirectory)
      .listFiles.filter(_.getName.takeRight(3) == "jpg")

    val randomIndex = _rand.nextInt(files.length)
    val imageFile = files(randomIndex)
```

Also

```
private val _jsonConfigFile = "/public/data/data.json"
def writeJsonToFile(content: String) = {
    import java.io._

    val pw = new PrintWriter(Play.getFile(_jsonConfigFile))
    pw.write(content)
    pw.close
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? Isn't it a problem of access rights for the user who is running the process?

Comment: It could be, but I thought I set these correctly. It is inside a JAR, so I can't check

Answer (score 0):

After `dist` the public/ directory is packaged into the application jar, which is put on the classpath, so you cannot access it through the filesystem or write to it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. Is there an alternative? Either on deployment strategy or in writing?

Comment: The best approach is to use S3 + CloudFront or something similar that is really targeted at serving static assets from the file system.

Comment: Thanks James. Specifically I'm trying to read files from an image directory (so they can be updated on demand) and read/write to a config file. It sounds like I need to serve them from somewhere else (such as Nginx). But if I use nginx can I still use Play.getFile("/assets/images") for IO if that directory is not served from Play?

Comment: Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Depends very much on your needs, but one way you could do it (if you do not need to scale out) is just use somewhere on your server filesystem and use the ExternalAssets router that comes with play to serve it.